# why is a minus sign prepended to my biginteger?

Tags: java

```
package ewa;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.math.BigInteger;
/**
 *
 * @author Lotus
 */
public class md5Hash {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String test = "abc";

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        try {
            md.update(test.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] result = md.digest();
            BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(result);
            String hex = bi.toString(16);
            System.out.println("Pringting result");
            System.out.println(hex);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(md5Hash.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
}
```

i am testing conversion of byte to hex and when done, the end result has a minus sign on the beginning of the string, why does this happen? i have read the docs and it says it will add a minus sign, however i do not understand it. And will the minus sign affect the hash result? because i am going to implement it to hash password stored on my database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `BigInteger` happens to be negative, meaning the most significant bit is 1.  If you want a positive number, use the [sign-magnitude constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20byte[]%29):

```
new BigInteger(1, result)
```

I'm not clear why you're implementing your own MD5 hash wrapper.  Why can't you just store the hash as a BINARY or BLOB?

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem. i am just implementing a very simple hash for my website, and do not know what you mean by storing the hash as a binary or blob

Comment: @kyrogue, for e.g. MySQL, see [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html).  It should be similar for other databases.  Using a binary type avoids the step of converting the hash to a string.  You should also consider using another hash, like SHA-256, since MD5 is now considered weak.

Comment: i am going to use microsoft access for the database, it is a very simple school project, by showing a md5hash on the password in the database, it allows me to get some extra marks

Comment: @kyrogue, MS Access [also has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208866%28v=office.12%29.aspx) the BINARY type.

Comment: hey, thanks, but if i am not wrong, my school uses MS access 2002 , so it do not have a binary datatype, unless i can set it somehow

Comment: @kyrogue, I think you're right.  According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902657%28SQL.80%29.aspx), Access 2002 did not have `BINARY`.

Answer (score 0):

BigIntegers are signed. In the byte representation, if the top bit is set, this shows as a negative number. One way around this is might be to append a 0 to the start of the array.